# Why are open carry laws opposite of what would be expected in Oregon and Florida?

Tags: united-states, guns, florida, oregon

Oregon allows open carry of firearms without a permit; Florida does not allow it, and does not issue permits for it. Both states require permits for concealed carry, with similar requirements.

Why is Oregon more permissive than Florida, when liberal states usually regulate guns more strictly than conservative states?

Comment: I'd guess Oregon has a lot of hunters, which maybe Florida doesn't. But you seem to be asking multiple things here.

Comment: @StuartF maybe I should remove #2 and post it as a separate question?

Comment: @StuartF Note that Florida has open carry allowance for hunting, camping and fishing.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the population centers of Oregon being solid democrat strong holds, they are all in Coastal Oregon.  Oregon's interior is less developed and more rugged (and reliably Red otherwise) and tend to have areas where a gun is still needed for survival.

Florida, despite a largely undeveloped interior (Name me the largest city in Florida without a coast line OR a giant mouse as a resident.  Without google.  I'll wait.), the coastal is largely developed and densly populated and the state has a sizeable population from norther liberal states living in its largest population centers (Florida's southern population has more in common with the Northern states, while its northern population has more in common with Southern states).  Florida is a lot more prone to swing politics, so the agendas of those in office tend to change dramatically between election cycles.   Finally, Florida is very much aware of it's status as "The Oddball" and while Oregon has its own weirdos, they tend to be found in one part (Portland) whereas no one would doubt that stricter gun use laws for Florida Man is the best way to keep the Florida Man off the endangered species list.

Comment: The I-5 corridor is not on the Oregon Coast.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- correct; it's roughly 100 km from the coast, whereas the eastern part of the state is more like 600 km from the coast.